# Model doesn't change when modify view elements in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am validating model's attribute (Name), in order to make sure, customer have to input their name in the register form.

**View :**

```
define(["jquery" ,
 "underscore" ,
 "backbone" ,
 "text!templates/CustomerTemplate.html",
 "models/Customer"
],function($ , _ , Backbone, CustomerTemplate, CustomerModel){
 var CustomerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
    events : {
        'submit #customerForm' : 'Customer'
    },
    Customer : function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var _customer = new CustomerModel({
            UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            Sex: 0,
            Name: $("#name").val(),
        });
        this.model.save(_customer,{validate: true},{
                wait:true,
                success:function(model, response) {
                    console.log('Successfully saved!');
                },
                error: function(model, error) {
                    console.log(model.toJSON());
                    console.log('error.responseText');
                }
        });
    },
    render : function(){
        var customertemplate = _.template(CustomerTemplate);
        this.$el.html(customertemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
 });
 return CustomerView;
});
```

**Model:**

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone"],function(_ , Backbone){
 var CustomerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "myurl",
    initialize : function(){
        this.bind('invalid', function(model, error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
    validate: function (attrs){
        if ( !attrs.Name) {
            return 'You must provide a name';
        }
    },
    defaults : {
        UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        Sex: 0,
        Name: "",
    }
 });
 return CustomerModel;
});
```

Problem : Even the attribute  `Name` is not `null`, the error message in `validate` method still appears (`You must provide a name`).

Any idea what could be causing this is appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: If you console.log($("#name").val()) at the top of the customer function, do you get the name in the console correctly? You may need to find the right way to point to the DOM element you want to get the data out of, which may be something like this.$("#name").val()

Comment: @jontewks : console.log($("#name").val()) gets the value correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `this.model.save` in your CustomerView, you're passing it a new `Customer` model you instantiated in the previous statement. This isn't quite what you want; you either want to call `_customer.save()` to save the brand new model, or - more likely - you want to pass your new attributes to the existing model, and save that:

```
var newAttrs = {
        UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        Sex: 0,
        Name: $("#name").val(),
    };
this.model.save(newAttrs);
```

---

When you call `this.model.save(_customer, {validate: true})` in your existing code, that `Customer` model get passed to your `validate()` function. And that model doesn't have a `Name` attribute. It *does* have a `Name` property - you can access it via `_customer.get('Name')` - but you should follow the Backbone convention and presume that your validate method is getting a 'simple' JavaScript object, not a Backbone model.